# undefined reference with boost when I try to compile

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, boost-asio

i have lot of errors when i try to compile my server with boost.
Here, this is my makefile :

```
NAME    =       serveur

SRCS    =       Serveur/main.cpp                \
                Serveur/Client.cpp              \
                Serveur/Commande.cpp            \
                Serveur/My_exception.cpp        \
                Serveur/Network.cpp             \
                Serveur/Server.cpp

#####################################################                                                                                                                                                          

OBJS                    =       $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
CC                      =       g++
RM                      =       rm -f
CFLAGS                  =       -g -W -Wall -Werror
INCL                    =       ./Serveur/boost_1_47_0
LIB                     =       ./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/
NLIB                    =       -lboost_system -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_filesystem-mt

#####################################################                                                                                                                                                          

$(NAME) :       $(OBJS)
        @$(CC) $(OBJS) -I$(INCL) -L$(LIB) $(NLIB) -o $(NAME)
        @printf "\n \033[33m[Message]\033[39m Compilation under Linux done\n\n"

.cpp.o  :
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCL) -L$(LIB) $(NLIB) -c $< -o $@
        @printf " \033[34m[Compilation]\033[39m %s\n" $<

re      :       fclean all

all     :       $(NAME)

clean   :
        @$(RM) *~ $(OBJS)
        @printf " \033[31m[Delete] \033[39m%s\n" $(OBJS)

fclean  :       clean
        @$(RM) $(NAME)
        @printf "\n \033[31m[Delete] \033[39m%s\n\n" $(NAME)
```

After "googling" i found that it's necessary to put `-lboost_filesystem` but it's not working again and there are next errors :

```
Serveur/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
Serveur/main.o: In function `error_code':
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
Serveur/main.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
Serveur/Client.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
Serveur/Network.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
Serveur/Server.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/abad_a//rendulocal/tech3/cpp/babel-2014-abad_a/Serveur/./Serveur/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [serveur] Error 1
```

Anyone know why it's not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boost::filesystem` depends on `boost::system`, so you'll have to add `-lboost_system`, also.

Comment: Two things come to mind. First, in your `INCL` variable you have the directory `Serveur`, but in your `LIB` variable you have `Server`. So, is one of them misspelled? Second, if that doesn't work can you go to you lib directory and find the actual name of `libboost_filename` and post it.

Comment: of course : libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_47.lib libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_47.lib libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib libboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47.lib libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_47.lib libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_47.lib     libboost_wserialization-vc100-mt-1_47.lib libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib libboost_wserialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib

Comment: i only need boost::asio so when i compile it on Visual 2010 it's working but not on fedora

Comment: i put `-lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt` and i have less errors than before but i always have some of this

Comment: Try the following. `make clean`, change `-lboost_system-mt` to `-lboost_system-vc100-mt-1_47` and similarly for `filesystem`.  Then run again.

Comment: it's not working. i have the followin error : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-vc100-mt-1_47 when i put it

Comment: Then, I don't know. I'm sorry.

Comment: problem solved. i downloaded the last version of boost and compiled it under fedora. so it works but when i launch my program i have the following error : error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.48.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You are mixing up the windows and linux boost libraries: there is no ....vc100.. on linux

Comment: WRT your latest problem: add the directory where your boost binaries are to your path.

Comment: "add the directory where your boost binaries are to your path". did you mean to my environment variable ?

Comment: yes it worked. i set the LD_PRELOAD path to my environment. thanks for your help

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that argument order can matter. For me, the following works:
g++ -lboost_system -pthread test.cpp
But this:
g++ test.cpp -lboost_system -pthread
Gives the errors you encountered.

Comment: My understanding is that the libraries link in that order: libA requires libB, so you have to put them in that order.

Answer (score 2):

I am using cygwin and the solution to this problem was linking the libraries

```
libboost_filesystem-mt
libboost_system-mt
```

The invocation of the linker looked like this:

```
g++  -o "bin.exe"  ./src/reader.o  ./src/bin.o -llibboost_filesystem-mt -llibboost_system-mt
```