# Compiler Command Line in Qt (Boost Related)

Tags: c++, qt, boost, command-line-arguments

I have a problem when using `<boost/thread.hpp>` in my code. When I try to compile it in Qt, I get these errors:

undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()`
undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()`
undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()`
error: ld returned 1 exit status

Anyway, I searched StackOverflow and found this:
[Undifined Reference With Boost When I Try To Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194313/undefined-reference-with-boost-when-i-try-to-compile)

They say the key to solve this problem is adding `-lboost_system`. But where should I add this?? :( I'm a newbie in boost and Qt and I want don't wanna compile my programs using command-line directly. Is there a way to add these command-line options to Qt Creator?

I use Qt 5 with MinGW compiler and Boost 1.53. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your `.pro` file:

```
LIBS += -L<their location> -lboost_system
```

I'm assuming that you have the `boost_system` library installed in a place the compiler will look of course.

Comment: It says:
cannot find -lboost_system

Comment: @MohammadRezaHajianpour Do you even have the boost libraries installed?  For MinGW on Windows you have to build it manually.

Comment: Yes, I have installed it. There are some dlls in stage/lib and bin.v2 is 2.28 GB full of files. I installed it last night.

Comment: @MohammadRezaHajianpour Then you just need to tell `qmake` where they are, or move them to a place where Windows will look for them (`system32` for example).  See my edit.

Comment: And where is the exact location? stage/lib? Where?

Comment: Please help. :\ Which location should I give as parameter.

Comment: @MohammadRezaHajianpour How would I know where the files are on *your* computer?  Search for a dll called `boost_system`.

Comment: You mean `libboost_system-mgw47-1_53.dll` files?

Comment: @MohammadRezaHajianpour That's the one, I couldn't remember what extra bits MinGW adds on.  I use Linux so I don't have to worry about such things :)

Comment: Damn. That doesn't work either. :( Says cannot find `-lboost_system` :( But I'm quite sure your answer is correct. Thanks. Any suggestions?

Comment: You just said the file's called `libboost_system-mgw47-1_53.dll`, so wouldn't it be that (minus the `.dll`)?

Comment: @MohammadRezaHajianpour Great example: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5994

Comment: YEA! THANKS MAN! IT WORKS! :D You solved the problem. I was losing hope! NICE JOB! :)